# c++: How to write a std::bind-like object that checks for superfulous parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind, for `std::bind`

> Member function operator()
>
> ...
>
> If some of the arguments that are supplied in the call to g() are not
>   matched by any placeholders stored in g, the unused arguments are
>   evaluated and discarded.

Quoting the examples, one can do:

```
void f(int n1, int n2, int n3, const int& n4, int n5) {
    std::cout << n1 << ' ' << n2 << ' ' << n3 << ' ' << n4 << ' ' << n5 << '\n';
}

int main() {
    auto f1 = std::bind(f, _2, _1, 42, std::cref(n), n);
    n = 10;
    f1(1, 2, 1001); // 1 is bound by _1, 2 is bound by _2, 1001 is unused
}
```

If you treat `f1` as a function with 5 parameters where 3 are fixed, you shouldn't be able to call `f1` with 3 parameters by common sense. However, as shown in above code, you are allowed to do so because the extra parameter is silently ignored.

According to [Why do objects returned from bind ignore extra arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251976/why-do-objects-returned-from-bind-ignore-extra-arguments), this behavior appears to exist because it is convenient to implement??.

To me, this is a rather confusing library feature as it messes up the arity of functions (e.g. 5 - 3 = 3 in above example) and defeats reasoning about function calls. I was wondering if there are any practical use cases in which this kind of behavior is actually beneficial?

More importantly, is it possible to implement a variant of `std::bind` to forbid this behavior? What are the possibilities and difficulties here.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use std::function directly?

Comment: `std::bind` operates on `std::function` but is not a `std::function`. IMO, `bind` is like a lazy partial application of functions, with possible parameter switching and this additional (error-prone) behavior.

Comment: "If you treat the bind result f1 above as a function or converted to a std::function, you wouldn't be able to call f1 with the wrong number of parameters." False. If you bind or convert it to `function<void(int, int, int)>`, you would be able to call it with three parameters, just as your example does.

Comment: Refined/corrected the statement to state my point in terms of common sense.

Comment: or in functional terms.

Comment: Is lambda enough as a solution?

Comment: Isn't lambda like `std::function`, something manipulated by `bind` but itself not a `bind` like operation?

Comment: Something like this? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14f42290ddb53cb8

Comment: Btw, cppreference's page for [`is_bind_expression`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/is_bind_expression) shows another reason why accepting additional arguments may be intended.

Comment: @dyp, Thanks for your code. I looks indeed like what I am looking for. Is it true your code has only one call `operator()`? If so, that would be a great feature.

Comment: Also, I was wondering if it is possible/not too cumbersome to revise your code such that it applies the function when all parameters of the bind target is bound. If so, that will make strict_bind also strict in the sense of function application. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247882/c11-bind-and-apply?rq=1

Comment: @dyp In any case, if you make an answer, it will what my question is looking for.

Comment: My `strict_binder` has a function template `operator()`, i.e. it has a (potential) overload set of `operator()`s. -- It is possible and quite simple (via tag dispatch) to rewrite the `strict_bind` to call the function instead of returning a binder *if there are no place-holder arguments*: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35b66c5b59050f1c

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks. I wish I could accept your comments as an answer.

Comment: I'll post an answer tomorrow ;)

Comment: @dyp When you do, do you mind including both versions of `strict_bind`?, say `strict_bind` and `apply`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Restricting the number of arguments breaks a feature of binders that is illustrated [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/is_bind_expression).

My solution is based on <strike>counting the passed placeholders</strike> determining the greatest placeholder used. Thanks to [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo) for pointing out this error.

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<class T, class U>
constexpr auto c_max(T&& t, U&& u)
-> typename std::remove_reference<decltype( t > u ? t : u )>::type
{  return t > u ? t : u;  }

template<class...>
struct max_placeholder : std::integral_constant<int, 0> {};

template<class T, class... Rest>
struct max_placeholder<T, Rest...>
: std::integral_constant<int, c_max(std::is_placeholder<T>::value,
                                    max_placeholder<Rest...>::value)>
{};
```

This lays the burden to correctly count the number on the user of the binder. For some bound Callables such as function pointers, it is possible to deduce the number of arguments (this also allows automatically supplying the required amount of placeholders). Once you have fixed the number of arguments either way, it's easy to write a wrapper that stores a binder and provides an `operator()` template that checks the number of arguments:

```
template<class T, int N>
struct strict_binder
{
    T binder;

    template<class... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args)
    -> decltype( binder(std::forward<Args>(args)...) )
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == N, "wrong number of arguments");
        return binder(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

It is also possible to produce a substitution failure instead of an error.

As the `strict_binder` is a `binder`, you can express this concept via a partial specialization:

```
namespace std
{
    template<class T, int N>
    struct is_bind_expression< strict_binder<T, N> >
        : public true_type
    {};
}
```

---

All that remains is to write a function template that produces `strict_binder`s. Here's a version that's similar to `std::bind`:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
auto strict_bind(F&& f, Args&&... args)
-> strict_binder<
       typename std::decay<
            decltype( std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...) )
       >::type,
       max_placeholder<typename std::remove_reference<Args>::type...>::value
   >
{
    return { std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...) };
}
```

Essentially, the return type is a

```
strict_binder<decltype(std::bind(f, args...)), count_placeholders<Args...>::value>
```

That is, the `strict_binder` stores the resulting type of `std::bind`.

---

You can also write an `apply`-like function that calls the bound function when no placeholders have been passed:

```
template<int N, class F, class... Args>
auto strict_bind_or_call(std::integral_constant<int, N>, F&& f, Args&&... args)
-> strict_binder<
       typename std::decay<
            decltype( std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...) )
       >::type,
       N
   >
{
    return { std::bind( std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)... ) };
}

template<class F, class... Args>
auto strict_bind_or_call(std::integral_constant<int, 0>, F&& f, Args&&... args)
-> decltype( std::bind( std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)... ) () )
{
    return std::bind( std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)... ) ();
}

template<class F, class... Args>
auto strict_bind(F&& f, Args&&... args)
-> decltype( strict_bind_or_call( std::integral_constant<int, max_placeholder<typename std::remove_reference<Args>::type...>::value>{},
                                  std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)... ) )
{
    using max_placeholder_here =
        max_placeholder<typename std::remove_reference<Args>::type...>;

    return strict_bind_or_call( max_placeholder_here{},
                                std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
```

This uses tag dispatch to either return a binder or the result of calling the function.
I gave up formatting this properly, you might want to introduce alias templates in a `detail` namespace.

Note the `decltype( std::bind(..) () )` in the second overload of `strict_bind_or_call` is a simple way to reproduce the semantics of `INVOKE` / `bind`; I can't just write `f(args...)` because `f` might be a member function.

---

Usage example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int p0, int p1)
{ std::cout << "[" << p0 << ", " << p1 << "]\n"; }

int main()
{
    auto f0 = strict_bind(foo, std::placeholders::_1, 42);
    f0(1);

    strict_bind(foo, 1, 2);
}
```

Comment: Note that `is_placeholder` does not just return 0 or 1, so for `count_placeholders<_1_t, _2_t, _3_t>`, you would get 6. You also need not the number of placeholders, but the value of the highest placeholder, i.e. a `max` meta-function. If the highest placeholder is `_3`, well, then you need 3 arguments, even if there is no `_1` or `_2`.