# std::bind-like function returning a std::function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, bind

I need a `bind` function that behaves like `std::bind`, but returns an appropriate specialization of `std::function`.

I think the `std::function` template arguments can be extracted using the placeholder number from the function's parameter. This doesn't look that trivial though. Is there any implementation available already?

---

## Why I need this

I want to implement a `waterfall` function with a semantics similar to [this JavaScript one](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall).

Here is how I imagine it would look like in C++:

```
std::function<void(const std::string &)> f = waterfall(
  []( const std::function<void(int)> &cb, const std::string & ) {
    ...;
    cb( 1 );
  },
  []( const std::function<void(double, double)> &cb, int ) {
    ...;
    cb(0.5, 10);
  },
  []( double, double ) {
  }
);
```

In other words, `waterfall` would take a bunch of functions, each of which (but the last one) takes a function as the first parameter. `waterfall` will bind every function to the previous one (starting from the last one, of course), and return a single function.

Basically waterfall should be something like this:

```
// recursion termination: `waterfall` called with a single functions
template< typename Arg >
auto waterfall( const Arg& first ) -> decltype( first ) {
  return first;
}
// recursion: `waterfall` called with mulitple functions
template< typename Arg, typename... Args >
... waterfall( const Arg& first, Args... args ) {
  return std::bind( first, waterfall(std::forward<Args>(args)...) );
}
```

There are three open problems though:

1. Figuring out the return type of `waterfall` when called with multiple arguments. It cannot be `decltype( std::bind(first, waterfall(...)) )` (because C++ doesn't allow recursively calling a template function to deduce its type). If I knew the type of the function (i.e. `Arg`), that, without the first argument, would be the return type I'm looking for.
2. I think I need to know the number of arguments of `first` in order to correctly `std::bind` it.
3. `std::bind`'s return type doesn't behave the way I want: nesting `std::bind` calls *merges* all the bound functions together, rather than composing them.

I was able to bypass the third point by writing an `std::bind` wrapper that wraps the bound function into an object of a type `T` such that `std::is_bind_expression<T>::value == false`.

For the first two points I need to find out the return type and the arguments type of `waterfall` parameters. This would be trivial if the functions were `std::function`s. It would also be simple if they are lambdas, classical functions, or functors with a single `operator()`: I'd just need to use something like [this `function_traits`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943765). However I'd *really* like to pass functions bound using `std::bind` to `waterfall`, without having to manually cast them into `std::function`s, because that makes my code *way* shorter and *way* clearer with large `waterfall`s.

Any ideas, thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: In C++11, you should prefer using lambda expressions over `std::bind` and friends.  Can you show an example for what you want to do?  Note that lambda closures are implicitly convertible to `std::function`s.

Comment: Can you explain how you intend to use this?  And why you think you need it?  In general, you cannot deduce a unique signature for a function call object, let alone one that has some arguments bound.  Almost always the consumer of an object knows how it is going to call the object, and as such should be the one determining the type of the erasure, not the supplier of the callable object.  The most common half-valid reason is you are writing a remote call protocol (from a different memory space, or a different language) and even there the protocol interface should determine the signature!

Comment: There is one answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21788988/683218 (by dyp) to my question about how to return a bind-like object that does not allow superfluous parameters. I don't know if it's relevant or whether you can adapt it to return a std::function object.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Why should I avoid using `std::bind`? `std::bind` is way simpler to type, especially if the bound function (i.e. the lambda) has a bunch of arguments.

Comment: @Yakk: I need an` std::function` (or something similar -- a lambda would be fine as well, of course), because I need to statically find out the type of its parameter, and -as far as I know- I cannot do this with the object returned by `std::bind`. Using a lambda would work, but I'd rather use a `bind` function, since it's easier to type...

Comment: @tinlyx: uh, yeah, a `bind` implementation would definitely help to my purpose, thanks.

Comment: @peoro Why do you need to statically find out the type of its parameter?  For what purpose?  You cannot do this with a function object in general, let alone the result of a binding: there are hacks cases that will be increasingly narrow in the future.  We get questions about this daily on this website: they are almost all for mistaken reasons.  `std::function` is not a type of a generic callable, it is a class that lets you type erase details of calling a callable -- if you are deducing the type to type erase to, you are almost always making a mistake.  Deduction and type erasure are opposite!

Comment: @Yakk: thanks for the explanation, although I'll need a while to fully understand it.
I wanted to write a `waterfall` function, that takes a number of functions all of which (but the last one) have a `std::function` as their first argument. `waterfall` should bind each of them to the previous one (starting from the last one, of course), and return a single function. Is this doable in C++? I believe I'd be able to implement it using a number of `std::function`s.

Comment: @peoro What do you want to do with arguments, feed them in turn to each of them, like consuming them?  Feed the arguments to all of them?  Feed all the arguments to the first one?  Or will `waterfall` return a nullary (zero-argument) function?

Comment: Or do you want to pass args to each of the waterfalled functions separately, like `waterfall(a,b,c)(1)(2,3)(4.5,6.7)`?

Comment: @Yakk: each function would pass the arguments to the inner one. The result of `waterfall` may have arguments itself.
Here an example: `waterfall( []( std::function<void(int)> f ){ ...; f(1); }, []( int ){ ... } )`.
Imagine this using more functions, each of which may take more arguments.
Basically I'm trying to implement something kind of semantically similar to [this JavaScript function](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall).

Comment: This is a chatroom conversation, not a Q&A.

Comment: `waterfall` would be a simple recursive variadic template function, that simply does something like `return bind( first, waterfall(args...) );`. At least I think/hope this should work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: you're right. Should I delete this question, and open a new one asking my final aim (i.e. implementing the `waterfall` thing?

Comment: @peoro: Might be wise :)

Comment: [cough](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/158f0d53e7641f3f) (C++14, but that just takes work to convert to C++11)  Do ask the question, and feel free to steal that code and self-answer.  If you want to deserve it, convert the C++14 stuff to C++11.  ;)

Comment: Edited this answer, rather than starting a new one... The reason is that in the edit I'm just explaining my need, but my real answer is still "how to have a `std::bind` that returns a `std::function`. @Yakk: uh, I know basically nothing about C++14. Anyway thanks a lot for your code, "function return type deduction" looks so sweet! Would that work if the parameters of `waterfall` were the result of a `std::bind`? That's my main goal (and because of that, finding the `waterfall` return type, or writing a `helper` function in C++11 is all but trivial).

Comment: _"It cannot be `decltype`... because C++ doesn't allow recursively calling a template function to deduce its type."_ You can work around this limitation by doing the recursion in a non-template function of a class template: http://ideone.com/nmnITN. C++14 function return type deduction does not have this limitation: http://ideone.com/BRo5D8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design here is to do most of the work within a helper class `details::waterfall` with 2-function waterfall style composition is done in `waterfall_call`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <string.h>

namespace details {
```

This would be slightly more efficient if I decayed outside of the structure definition, as it would reduce unique types in some cases.  I don't care:

```
  template<class F0, class F1>
  struct waterfall_call {
    typename std::decay<F0>::type f0;
    typename std::decay<F1>::type f1;
```

Call f0 passing it f1 and args...:

```
    template<class...Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args)const
    -> typename std::result_of<F0 const&(F1 const&,Args...)>::type
    {
      return f0( f1, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    }
  };
```

The center of the algorithm:

```
  struct waterfall {
```

For 2 args, just use `waterfall_call`:

```
    template<class F0, class F1>
    waterfall_call<F0, F1> operator()( F0&& f0, F1&& f1 )const
    {
      return { std::forward<F0>(f0), std::forward<F1>(f1) };
    }
```

For >2 args, recurse, then do a 2 arg solution:

```
    template<class F0, class...Fs,
      class I=typename std::result_of<waterfall const&(Fs...)>::type
    >
    auto operator()( F0&& f0, Fs&&... fs )const
    -> typename std::result_of< waterfall( F0, I ) >::type
    {
      auto child = (*this)( std::forward<Fs>(fs)... );
      return (*this)( std::forward<F0>(f0), std::move(child) );
    }
```

For 1 arg, just forward out to a decayed version of the input arg:

```
    template<class F0>
    auto operator()(F0&&f0)const
    ->typename std::decay<F0>::type
    {
      return std::forward<F0>(f0);
    }
  };
}
```

And `waterfall` itself just delegates to `details::waterfall`:

```
template<class...Fs>
auto waterfall(Fs&&... fs )
-> typename std::result_of<details::waterfall(Fs...)>::type{
  return details::waterfall{}( std::forward<Fs>(fs)... );
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a6afc6d3f1f6549)

The other way (besides the `struct` trick above) of getting around recursive template return type deduction limitations is to take a parameter by template type from the namespace of the function, and pass it to your recursive calls.  This enables ADL lookup, which can recursively find your own function even when deducing your own return type.